# Delete SharePoint Online file versioning with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, versioning

I was searching for a way to clean up SharePoint to free up some space when I stumbled upon some PowerShell scripts to delete some versions of a file in SharePoint Online.
Let's say your tenant is set to have 500 version of a file, you want to delete the versioning for old files that you just don't want to delete but also don't need the 500 versions of it.

That being said I am struggling on how to connect with SharePoint Online, chose a specific site, a specific file and then delete all the version.
I found this script on Internet, and was looking into it but it seems that I am supposed to have some prerequisite that I do not meet in order to use this script.
For instance I don't understand the `Add-Type -Path` part, from what I understand this script is meant to work on SharePoint server and not SharePoint Online.

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

#Config Parameters
$SiteURL= "https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/sales/"
$FileURL="/Sites/Sales/ProjectDocuments/ProjectMetrics.xlsx"

#Setup Credentials to connect
$Cred = Get-Credential
$Cred = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.UserName,$Cred.Password)

Try {
    #Setup the context
    $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
    $Ctx.Credentials = $Cred

    #Get the File
    $File = $Ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl($FileURL)

    #Get all versions of the file
    $Versions = $File.Versions
    $Ctx.Load($Versions)
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    Write-host -f Yellow "Total Number of Versions Found :" $Versions.count

    #Delete all versions of the file
    $Versions.DeleteAll()
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    Write-host -f Green "All versions Deleted for given File!"  
}
Catch {
    write-host -f Red "Error deleting versions!" $_.Exception.Message
}
```

Especially when using the Get-SPWeb cmdlet I get this error message:

```
Get-SPWeb : The term 'Get-SPWeb' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-SPWeb
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-SPWeb:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Any help and clarification would be very appreciated, thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested the same PowerShell in my side, it's working as expected:

[image]

In the error message in origianl question, Get-SPWeb is used in On-Premise SharePoint not SharePoint Online.

For SharePoint Online, please download and insatll SharePoint Online CSOM Here:

[SharePoint Online Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038)

After installing, the PowerShell should be working.

Comment: Hey, I have installed the SharePoint Online Client Components SDK that you provided, unfortunately, it's still not working on my side.
Would you mind telling me if there is any other prerequisite ? Are you running the script in a regular PowerShell terminal or the SharePoint Online management shell ?

Comment: Is there any error message in your side ? The PowerShell actually working in my side.

I run in a normal PowerShell ISE without more configuration.

If you are still having the issue, try to download SharePoint Online Manageshell and run PowerShell in it directly:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35588

This is the managementshell which can run SharePoint Online PowerShell directly.

Comment: I've tried all of this, the script is actually running and I believe it's working, however i'm being stopped during the execution with the following error message `ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.`

Comment: Did you have enough permission in the target SharePoint site and list ? Try to sign in with a full control account.

Comment: I do sign in with a Full Controle, that's why I'm confused about this error, I'm looking into permissions again and will try to figure out the needed permission. Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: Hi LeanneKami, Did you have any update on permission ?

Comment: Hello, after updating the code, I finally managed to get it to run.
I finally realized that my file path was wrong because it's display as /Site/Document/whatever_here in my Explorer but the actual Path is /Site/Share Documents/whatever_here
Which makes a huge difference ! I feel stupid but at least it's working now !